# Toggle slow animation while debugging with iOS Device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

I'm using xCode 4.3.1 and I need to use the option that the iOS Simulator has => Debug -> Toggle Slow Animation but while debugging with the iOS Device.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

It's not possible in exactly the same way as with the Simulator, but there is a good way to accomplish the same effect using lldb.

Use the debugger to pause code execution, and then enter the command:

```
p [(CALayer *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] layer] setSpeed:.1f]
```

into the debugger.

Thanks to [this link](http://gavrix.wordpress.com/2013/03/16/how-to-toggle-slow-animations-on-device/) for the solution.

Comment: It's worth noting that this can be simplified to `[self.window.layer setSpeed:.1f];` if used at runtime in the app delegate's `-application:didFinishLaunching…:` method. (Assuming you're still using the `window` property that the app delegate template gives you by default, of course.)

Comment: Great answer, this is even better then the Simulator, I had a lot of animation running on the same time, 0.1F is still too fast for me, so I set it to 0.02F. And now i can see where the bug is. :D:D:D THANX A LOOOOOOT

Comment: This can be simplified in lldb to just `expr -- [(UIApplication *)UIApp keyWindow].layer.speed = 0.1f`

Comment: Or even `[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows[0] layer].speed = .1f;` at runtime

Answer (score 26):

In Swift 3:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.layer.speed = 0.1
```

Or, if you're anywhere in your AppDelegate and you only use one window, you can do this:

```
window?.layer.speed = 0.1
```

Answer (score 19):

For **Swift** Apps:

Halt your code with a breakpoint and enter the following lldb command:

**`(lldb)`** `p UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.layer.speed = 0.1`

---

Alternatively you can obviously also change the speed somewhere in you code. For example with an `#if` preprocessor macro at application launch

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool 
{
    ...

    #if DEBUG
        application.windows.first?.layer.speed = 0.1
    #endif
```

Don't forget to set the `DEBUG` symbol in the "Swift Compiler - Custom Flags" section, "Other Swift Flags" line. You add the `DEBUG` symbol with a `-DDEBUG` entry.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5, add this line in AppDelegate or SceneDelegate class, that's depending on your base architecture :

```
// create and assign window object if not exist. 
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

// starts slow motion 
window?.layer.speed = 0.05
```

Comment: Worth noting that this is the fantastic modern answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to slow down the app only in one view controller, you can configure a breakpoint to continue execution after executing the command.
You set this breakpoint in `viewDidAppear`.
Then you can set another "non-stoppable" breakpoint to reverse the speed to 1X.
You set this other breakpoint in `viewDidDisappear`.

Very simple. 
Can be kept in your breakpoint list deactivated and easily reused when needed.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-c works pretty good

```
self.window.layer.speed = .1f;
```